# How can I make smooth round corners?

Tags: modeling, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

As you can see in the picture, I want to create this rectangular are which has **4 straight corners** on the inside and **4 round corners** on the outside. The outside round corners appear as pixelated but I need them smooth and round because I am animating a cutting procedure with a milling machine.

I prefer to use the brushing tool but if you have any other way to do it let me know. I just need to make the object look like is being cut in the real time. So that blue part has to look like it is being cut.

Thank you in advance.

[image]